# How to add contextmenu in control which has original contextmenu?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I'm going to add customizing contextMenuStrip to a control which has already default contextMenuStrip .

Code snippet :

```
   DBDisplay imageControl = new DBDisplay(); // This is third-party object
   imageControl.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStripTableLayout;
```

However, default contextMenu has been changed new contextMenu. I'd like to use default + new contextMenu. Is there any tip or help ?

Thanks Grant. I have one more question.

**updated edit**

```
           List<DBDisplay> m_pImage = new List<DBDisplay>();
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               DBDisplay imageControl = new DBDisplay();
               imageControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
               imageControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
               imageControl.Size = new Size(columnWidth, rowHeight);

               foreach (ToolStripItem tsItem in contextMenuStripTableLayout.Items)
                   imageControl.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(tsItem);

               m_pImage.Add(imageControl);
           }

           int index = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
           {
                   //First add a column
                   tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, columnWidth));

                   for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
                   {

                       if (i == 0)
                       {
                           //defining the size of cell
                           tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, rowHeight));
                       }

                       tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(m_pImage[index], i, j);

                       index++;
                   }
               }
```

I have one more question. If I use above code, then imageControl contextMenuStrip has 10 times repeat. How can I solve this problem ?

**Update**
Basically, m_pImage list will be added in tableLayoutPanel1 control. I'm going to use each column and row contextmenustrip.  Is it correct to approach or not ?

**Update2** Ok, here is detail source code. DBDisplay is DBCogDisplay.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Cognex.VisionPro.Display;

namespace DBSubClass
{
    public partial class DBCogDisplay : Cognex.VisionPro.Display.CogDisplay
    {
        public DBCogDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetLayoutSettings();
            SetStyleSettings();
        }

        public DBCogDisplay(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);
            InitializeComponent();
            SetLayoutSettings();
            SetStyleSettings();
        }

        private void SetLayoutSettings()
        {
            base.AllowDrop = true;
            base.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            base.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            base.MouseWheelMode = CogDisplayMouseWheelModeConstants.Zoom1;
            base.ContextMenuStrip.AllowMerge = true;
        }

        private void SetStyleSettings()
        {
            base.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            UpdateStyles();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Object description of CogDisplay class. 
http://www.hyperbook.com/cognex/vpro/ja/Cognex.VisionPro.Display.CogDisplay.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `ContextMenuStrip`, try using [ToolStripManager.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5523fet0.aspx). I have *no* idea if this will work in your case, but normally it takes all the items in the first menu and merges them into the second menu. I've used this on two instances of `ContextMenuStrip` before, but I don't know what a `DBDisplay` is or how it's designed internally.

```
if (ToolStripManager.Merge(imageControl.ContextMenuStrip, newContextMenuStrip))
    imageControl.ContextMenuStrip = newContextMenuStrip;
```

---

First you said `ContextMenu`, but then your control seems to actually implement a `ContextMenuStrip`. Just in case, for a `ContextMenu` you could try using [Menu.MergeMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.mergemenu%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
imageControl.ContextMenu.MergeMenu(newContextMenu);
```

---

Edit: *(after Changju updated the original question)*

You're merging all 10 `imageControl` menus into `contextMenuStripTableLayout`, so you're seeing the menu items repeated 10 times.

I think you'll just have to add them using a loop instead:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem tsItem in contextMenuStripTableLayout.Items)
    imageControl.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(tsItem);
```

Comment: Thanks Grant. I have one more question. See above edited version.

Comment: If I take second idea, then I got CS1503 error. Cannot convert "ContextMenuStrip" to "Menu".

Comment: imageControl.contextMenuStrip.Items.Add(tsItem); correct ? However, I've got some error message in this code about InvalidOperationException. WHat shall I do ? Can you see my new update version ?